# Dingo API pagination with illuminate builder not eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, dingo-api, illuminate-container

I am in the process of starting to learn Laravel 5.3 and Dingo API to build a basic REST API. I am trying to return the paginated JSON representation of a report query result. I can get pagination to work using Eloquent models, however not when using the raw Illuminate QueryBuilder for DB access. Here is what I've been trying:

```
public function getWentCommission(Request $request, $start, $end)
{
    $filters = $request->input('filter');

    $query = DB::table('commissions')
            ->selectRaw("fields")
            ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'commissions.customerid')
            ->leftJoin('customers', 'customers.id', '=', 'commissions.customerid')
            ->whereBetween('datestart', [$start, $end])
            ->orWhereBetween('dateend', [$start, $end])
            ->orWhereNull('dateend')
            ->where('void', '=', 0)
            ->orderBy('startdate');

    // Filter by users?
    if($filters && array_key_exists('users', $filters))
    {
        $rawids = array_map('intval', array_unique(array_filter(explode(',', $filters['users']), 'is_numeric' )));
        $query = $query->whereIn('users.id', $rawids);
    }

    return $this->response->paginator(new IlluminatePaginatorAdapter($query->paginate(25)), new ObjectTransformer);
}
```

However, this only nets me the following error which I have yet to figure out how to resolve. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to League\Fractal\Pagination\IlluminatePaginatorAdapter::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator, instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection given
```